# What does 'measurable life' mean?

Tags: meaning

what does 'measurable life' mean? I found this usage in the end of a sentence that criticized the youth of today.

Update

I saw its usage in this comment: Insensibility is wide spread today. Market economy sets an unfortunate culture, 'it's me only.'Unfortunately, our youth is succumbed to it .. measurable life !

Comment: Pleas provide the complete sentence (and, ideally, the complete paragraph, or otherwise enough context for us to answer your question with any kind of certainty).

Comment: @jxh I have added the dialogue from where I found this usage. Would you like to revise your explanation?

Comment: @code_dweller: that reads like a criticism of capitalism: the author appears to be lamenting that market economies encourage us to *measure [the value of] our life* by our wealth.

Comment: Given the phrase "our youth is succumbed to it", I think you can dismiss the whole quote as bad English and not worth analyzing.

Comment: @keshlam: "is succumbed" is the present perfect tense, so the grammar is valid for that phrase.

Comment: The last sentence of what you quoted reads more like prose to me than a full sentence. Did the original text have those two dots?

Comment: @jxh: "has succumbed" would be correct and idiomatic. This is not idiomatic, and I do not believe it is correct except in the most forced of poetic formulations.

Comment: @DanBron Without this context, what would measurable life usage stand for? Can we use it simply like how we use the word 'humbug' for expressing disapproval or anger?

Comment: @jxh Yeah. I copy-pasted that dialogue

Comment: In this case, it seems a poetic turn of phrase, like a pun on "miserable life".

Comment: @code_dweller: since "*measurable life*" (unlike "*humbug*") is *not* an idiom, just a random pair of words, it does not have an independent meaning. So the only way to interpret it (understand its meaning) is through context, and indeed different contexts can lend it different meanings (whereas defined words and established idioms are much more reliable and robust). In other words: "measurable life" *doesn't mean anything*. Sorry. On the forum where you saw it used, I'm with jxh: it was probably a misspelling for [**miserable life**](http://www.damnyouautocorrect.com).

Answer (score 1):

*measurable* normally describes something which can be measured and I've seen it applied in the sense of "measurable life events", or events in life which we can clearly measure or quantify.

It's possible that your source is intending to say "miserable life", as in:

> Drinking kerosene has proven a dangerous pastime.  Unfortunately, our youth **have** succumbed to it...  Miserable life!